# Elixir dependency does not generate app file

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, hex-pm

I am about to release `0.2.0` of my myhtmlex library.
But I am having trouble testing my new package release, as the test application does not generate an app file.

And to test my integration, I wrote a script to test my hex releases in test-applications.

You can check the source here: https://github.com/Overbryd/myhtmlex/tree/package-test

The steps to reproduce this are:

1. Build the hex package `mix hex.build`
2. Unpack the resulting tar-archive
3. Create a new test-application depending on that hex package with `{:myhtmlex, path: "../local-tar-archive"}`
4. Build the test-application `mix compile` but it fails with:

   ```
   ==> myhtmlex
   Compiling 3 files (.ex)
   ==> myhtmlex_pkg_test
   Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
   * myhtmlex (../myhtmlex-local)
     could not find an app file at "_build/dev/lib/myhtmlex/ebin/myhtmlex.app". This may happen if the dependency was not yet compiled, or you specified the wrong application name in your deps, or the dependency indeed has no app file (then you can pass app: false as option)
   ** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies
   ```

Cross-post from: https://elixirforum.com/t/dependency-does-not-generate-app-file/12703

Comment: The branch no longer exists. Could it be a timestamp issue? Mix is thinking that the project is already compiled and it is trying to read the .app file, which is not there.

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you are not using elixir_make for handling the makefile bits?

Comment: I could nail down a "bug" or timestamp issue, that was resolved here: https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/515

Comment: `elixir_make` sounds great :) Thank you José for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with `hex >= 0.17.3` and using `mix hex.build --unpack -o package-test` directly solved this for me.

If you want to read up on the details of this, the issue was resolved here: https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/515